# Emplace method in own deque

Tags: c++, move-semantics, deque, emplace

How can I write my own emplace method in my deque?

For example, I have this emplace_front function

```
template <typename ... Args>
void emplace_front(Args&& ...val) {
???
}
```

and Node constructor

```
template <typename ... Args>
Node(Args&&... val) : element(std::forward<Args>(val)...), next(nullptr),prev(nullptr) { }
```

I can't figure out how to write it correctly

Comment: You use it with placement-new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a continuous container, it looks something like:

```
// first find/create free memory for your data, call it p
new (p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

This is called 'placement new', and does not allocate, only construct
`p` should be a `T*`

---

If you have a node-based container, it looks something like:

```
struct Node {
    Node *prev, *next;
    T value;
    template<typename... Args>
    Node(Args&&... args) : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template<typename... Args>
iterator emplace(Args&&... args) {
    Node* p = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // fill in p->next and p->prev here
    return {p};
}
```

you also need a constructor to your iterator that takes a `Node*`

Answer (score 0):

"Emplace" simply means to construct the object once and not move it (although, depending on the specifics of the container, a future operation on the container might move existing elements).

Your deque appears to be built out of nodes and pointers. In this kind of container, emplacement is easy. Just create a node (that holds an element constructed from the forward arguments) and then *don't move it*. Rearrange the pointers in order to insert the node into the data structure. For example, it might look something like this:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void emplace_front(Args&& ...val) {
    auto* node = new Node(std::forward<Args>(val)...);
    node->prev = head_;  // assuming it is circularly linked
    head_->next = node;
    node->next = front_;
    front_->prev = node;
    front_ = node;
    size_++;
}
```